# Microsoft Visual Studio is changing my parameters

Tags: visual-studio

Trying to run my program through the Microsoft Visual Studio debugger, and have added parameters in Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging in the `Command Arguments` field.

One of my parameters contains the string `"<u>"` and Visual Studio is changing it into `"<u xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">"`. This is both unexpected and unhelpful. My program does not expect nor wish to have all this extra stuff passed in instead of the string I am trying to pass in.

As an example, the parameter in question is `-nlp:"<u>"` and Visual Studio is changing it into `-nlp:"<u xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003>"`. The expected result is for it to stay as typed in: `-nlp:"<u>"`. This is one example, but there are in fact two parameters affected in this way. Both are "enhanced" with the addition of the same string. If I used other values, they are always affected the same way. It seems any string surrounded by angle brackets is fair game for this string embellishment.

[image: VS changing my parameters]

How do I configure Visual Studio not to make this change?

My VS version details are:-

Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012

Version 11.0.61219.00 Update 5

Comment: Can edit your post to include whole expected and result parameter? Is your parameter just "<u>" or anything else?

Comment: Hi @Matt. I have updated my post to clarify.

Comment: What about the rest of the parameters? I can see that <m> tag also has the http:// part.

Comment: What about "inherit from parent ..."? Is this checked? If yes, what's the parent's properties?

Comment: I guess it's probably due to way fact Visual Studio 2012 persists its parameters (note it's out of mainstream support). I can't reproduce on Visual Studio 2017. You could try to encode it like this `&lt;u&gt;` but this will probably require some processing in your code

Comment: @Matt - yes, any parameters that is angle bracket surrounded is affected in this way.

Comment: HI @Dominique - the screen shot shown is what you get when you click on <Edit...>, thus <inherit from parent or project defaults> is not selected. I tried selecting this, and it cleared my parameters completely, so I cancelled the property dialog to revert them. That would seem to suggest it is not selected too.

Comment: Hi @SimonMourier - I wasn't imaging that this was a defect in VS - someone would surely have noticed by now if it was. I assume I just have a setting somewhere that is obscure and I didn't know about it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a msbuild/vs project persistence issue. Can you try to 1) close VS, 2) edit your .csproj file and add a line like this in the first PropertyGroup xml element: `<StartArguments>blabla... -nlp:"&lt;u&gt;"</StartArguments>` see if it keeps it when you reopen (you may have to delete the .user file)

Comment: Hi @SimonMourier - from your comments, I was able to find the part of the XML file where my parameters were stored (<LocalDebuggerCommandArguments> in my .vcxproj.user file, and change those to use entities instead of the angle brackets, and then it worked. Initially I only changed `"<u>"` to `"&lt;u&gt;"` because that was the only part of the parameters that was being embelished, but then on startup VS complained that I didn't have matching tags! (because there was also an unembelished `"</u>"`. Once I changed both in the file all was well. Would you like to write up the answer for the bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does not seem to exist with Visual Studio 2017 or higher (I've not tested 2013 nor 2015).

How debug arguments are stored depends on project type packages (C, C#, C++, etc.), even if they are both using the MsBuild system.

Also, without manual intervention, debug arguments are not stored in the project file (.csproj, .vcxproj, etc.), but aside it in a .user file (so it can vary per user).

With Visual studio 2017, for an arguments like `-nlp:"<u>"`, for a C# project, the .user file looks like this

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <StartArguments>-nlp:"&lt;u&gt;"</StartArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

And for a C++ project, the .user file looks like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>-nlp:"&lt;u&gt;"</LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>
    <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

We see that these are correctly escaped and the `<` and `>` are transformed into their respective XML entities.

Visual Studio 2012 doesn't act the same, so the XML must be escaped manually. And the problem may be in MsBuild, not strictly in Visual Studio. Editing the appropriate .user file and manually escaping your `<` and `>` characters as shown above will work round the problem in Visual Studio 2012.